# Hardware based ECU flasher vs software

Tags: can, flash

Why all of the automotive flash equipment require a hardware to write/read Flash memories? (Such as kess/bflash etc)
It isn't possible with just a good quality OBD cable to connect to CAN BUS and read/write the flash memories?

Comment: It isn't. I have flashed MCUs via OBD (CAN).

Comment: So it works with just an OBD Cable? So why they make all these kind of hardware, and not just a single PC software with a good OBD Cable?

Comment: I think you are confusing a "cable" for an hardware interface between two systems and associated software. I have only done medium recent Bosch ECUs are they are flashable via OBD, so your question does not stand as is.

Answer (score 0):

Well to flash anything over an interface like CAN you must have software running on the ECU that knows how to flash itself, and such software typically needs to be able to recover from a failed attempt to flash cleanly.

It can be done obviously, but it typically requires significantly more flash to pull it off reliably, because you usually want to do it in a couple of steps : Download the new image into memory that is not currently in use, then have the (immutable) bootloader do the actual programming.

Note that most such processors execute in place, so your ability to erase flash while running is limited.

This costs money, not a lot but automotive are fierce on BOM cost of electronics, they do not like anything that adds cost, especially if they can move the cost out of the car and into the (far smaller) number of specialist service kits.

Do I add a dollar to the production cost of every car we ship or a thousand dollars to a few specialist garages tool kits (Which they will claim as a business expense and then actually make a profit on)?

Comment: Okay, but just a simple software without the hardware expenses costs (like kess) can cost much less. Above that you dont need to maintenance hardware at all since you will have a simple OBD Cable.

You might not have some features like power-loss , recovering etc, but still the solution without hardware seems much more efficiently to me if client or tuner is willing to take some risks. I mean that software should exists, but it doesn't.

Comment: No car company gives a shit about the aftermarket tuning scene, it makes no money for the car company and causes warranty issues! Further, writing that software running on the ECU to support flash over CAN is a cost, and given the manufacturer is flashing these things over JTAG anyway at production, why bother? The software doesn't exist because the code on the ECU does not support this, nothing the PC side can do about that.